# Founders of organisation using schema.org

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

How to define multiple founders of organisation in JSON+LD?

To create array named **founders** or **founder**? In array of course items of type *Person* with data about it.

I'm just not sure about array name because when I test on Google test tool I'm getting separate persons from array and it's confusing when each is called founders instead of founder.

**Update**

Here's example, I used here *founder* for an array.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "sameAs": [
    "https://instagram.com/x",
    "https://facebook.com/x",
    "https://twitter.com/x",
    "https://linkedin.com/company/x"
  ],
  "name": "X",
  "url": "https://x.com/",
  "telephone": "x",
  "contactPoint": {
    "@type": "ContactPoint",
    "telephone": "x",
    "availableLanguage": [
      "English"
    ],
    "contactType": "sales",
    "email": "x"
  },
  "logo": {
    "@type": "ImageObject",
    "url": "https://symbol.jpg",
    "width": "2000",
    "height": "2000"
  },
  "image": {
    "@type": "ImageObject",
    "url": "https://x.jpg",
    "width": "3840",
    "height": "1506"
  },
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "x",
    "addressLocality": "x",
    "addressRegion": "x",
    "postalCode": "x",
    "addressCountry": "x"
  },
  "founder": [
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "givenName": "x",
      "familyName": "x",
      "jobTitle": {
        "@type": "DefinedTerm",
        "name": "Chief Executives",
        "termCode": "11-1011.00",
        "description": "Determine and formulate policies and provide overall direction of companies or private and public sector organizations within guidelines set up by a board of directors or similar governing body. Plan, direct, or coordinate operational activities at the highest level of management with the help of subordinate executives and staff managers.",
        "inDefinedTermSet": "https://onetonline.org"
      }
    },
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "givenName": "x",
      "familyName": "x",
      "jobTitle": {
        "@type": "DefinedTerm",
        "name": "Web Developer",
        "termCode": "15-1134.00",
        "description": "Design, create, and modify Web sites. Analyze user needs to implement Web site content, graphics, performance, and capacity. May integrate Web sites with other computer applications. May convert written, graphic, audio, and video components to compatible Web formats by using software designed to facilitate the creation of Web and multimedia content.",
        "inDefinedTermSet": "https://onetonline.org"
      }
    }
  ],
  "employee": [
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "givenName": "x",
      "familyName": "x",
      "jobTitle": {
        "@type": "DefinedTerm",
        "name": "Graphic Designers",
        "termCode": "27-1024.00",
        "description": "Design or create graphics to meet specific commercial or promotional needs, such as packaging, displays, or logos. May use a variety of mediums to achieve artistic or decorative effects.",
        "inDefinedTermSet": "https://onetonline.org"
      }
    },
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "givenName": "x",
      "familyName": "x",
      "jobTitle": {
        "@type": "DefinedTerm",
        "name": "Web Developer",
        "termCode": "15-1134.00",
        "description": "Design, create, and modify Web sites. Analyze user needs to implement Web site content, graphics, performance, and capacity. May integrate Web sites with other computer applications. May convert written, graphic, audio, and video components to compatible Web formats by using software designed to facilitate the creation of Web and multimedia content.",
        "inDefinedTermSet": "https://onetonline.org"
      }
    },
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "givenName": "x",
      "familyName": "x",
      "jobTitle": {
        "@type": "DefinedTerm",
        "name": "Graphic Designers",
        "termCode": "27-1024.00",
        "description": "Design or create graphics to meet specific commercial or promotional needs, such as packaging, displays, or logos. May use a variety of mediums to achieve artistic or decorative effects.",
        "inDefinedTermSet": "https://onetonline.org"
      }
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

Comment: Could you post your screenshot from the testing tool? (Redact if necessary). If it's saying it's valid, then it's probably correct - but it would be easier to tell given a screenshot.

Comment: For reference: https://schema.org/Organization and https://schema.org/founder and https://schema.org/founders

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Google testing tool said that everything's correct in both cases, founders and founder. I updated question.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the documentation you will see that founder supersedes founders. So use founder with an array.

Comment: I don't see on schema.org where is says you can use an array, can you show where it allows that?   Can you give an example of the markup?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I updated the question, Google testing tool says it's ok.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller You're right. schema.org is not very clear on when a property can contain multiple values. I could not find any clear documentation on it. From experience they now use singular form for property names even if multiple entities are allowed. Hence the move from founders to founder. schema.org tries not to add restrictions like this. They also never say if a property is required. Those limitations are added by the consumer of the data, e.g. Google.